# What is generating this FZ Error message - From FreecessController

Tags: android

This message has started showing up in my Logcat.  I cannot find any documentation in searches for FreecessController or FZ Error.

FreecessController  system_server E  FZ error : com.grgmobilesolutions.peepsconnection(0)

Does anyone know where is comes from and/or the cause?

Comment: Did you get any information regarding this problem? I am also facing the same problem.